# Duplicate resources error in twopane layout aliasing in android studio 0.4.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have following error in Android studio 0.4.3,

```
Execution failed for task ':MyAppName:mergeDebugResources'.
> /my project path/src/main/res/values-sw720dp/refs.xml: Error: Duplicate resources: 
/my project path/src/main/res/values-sw720dp/refs.xml:layout-sw720dp/activity_configuration, /my project path/src/main/res/layout-sw720dp/activity_configuration.xml:layout-sw720dp/activity_configuration
```

**res/values-sw720dp/refs.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
    Layout alias to replace the single-pane version of the layout with a
    two-pane version on Large screens.

    For more on layout aliases, see:
    http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters
    -->

    <item name="activity_mymap" type="layout">@layout/activity_mymap_twopane</item>
    <item name="activity_configuration" type="layout">@layout/activity_configuration_twopane</item>
</resources>
```

**res/layout-sw720dp/activity_configuration.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/configuration_list"
    android:name="com.myWebsite.myApp.configurations.ConfigurationListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context="com.myWebsite.myApp.configurations.ConfigurationActivity"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created an alias with the same ID as an existing resource in the same directory -- you already have a **layout-sw720dp/activity_configuration** resource from your layout XML file, and in your **refs.xml** file, you're creating an alias with the ID `activity_configuration` in the same folder. You can either give your alias a different ID, or remove the redundant resource in the **layout-sw720dp** folder.

It's not clear to me what you need the alias for -- it seems like you should just put the two-pane version of the layout in the **layout-sw720dp** folder with the same ID as the single-pane version for smaller screens (`activity_configuration`), and not use the extra indirection of the resource alias. The small-screen, single-pane version of the file will go in **layout/activity_configuration**.